# Using categorical variables in statsmodels OLS class

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

I want to use `statsmodels` OLS class to create a multiple regression model.  Consider the following dataset:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dict = {'industry': ['mining', 'transportation', 'hospitality', 'finance', 'entertainment'],
  'debt_ratio':np.random.randn(5), 'cash_flow':np.random.randn(5) + 90} 

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict)

x = data[['debt_ratio', 'industry']]
y = data['cash_flow']

def reg_sm(x, y):
    x = np.array(x).T
    x = sm.add_constant(x)
    results = sm.OLS(endog = y, exog = x).fit()
    return results
```

When I run the following code:

```
reg_sm(x, y)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'
```

I've tried converting the `industry` variable to categorical, but I still get an error.  I'm out of options.

Comment: This is because 'industry' is categorial variable, but OLS expects numbers (this could be seen from its source code).  drop industry, or group your data by industry and apply OLS to each group.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're on the right path with converting to a Categorical dtype.  However, once you convert the DataFrame to a NumPy array, you get an `object` dtype (NumPy arrays are one uniform type as a whole).  This means that the individual values are still underlying `str` which a regression definitely is not going to like.

What you might want to do is to [dummify](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) this feature.  Instead of [factorizing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) it, which would effectively treat the variable as continuous, you want to maintain some semblance of categorization:

```
>>> import statsmodels.api as sm
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.random.seed(444)
>>> data = {
...     'industry': ['mining', 'transportation', 'hospitality', 'finance', 'entertainment'],
...    'debt_ratio':np.random.randn(5),
...    'cash_flow':np.random.randn(5) + 90
... }
>>> data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
>>> data = pd.concat((
...     data,
...     pd.get_dummies(data['industry'], drop_first=True)), axis=1)
>>> # You could also use data.drop('industry', axis=1)
>>> # in the call to pd.concat()
>>> data
         industry  debt_ratio  cash_flow  finance  hospitality  mining  transportation
0          mining    0.357440  88.856850        0            0       1               0
1  transportation    0.377538  89.457560        0            0       0               1
2     hospitality    1.382338  89.451292        0            1       0               0
3         finance    1.175549  90.208520        1            0       0               0
4   entertainment   -0.939276  90.212690        0            0       0               0
```

Now you have dtypes that statsmodels can better work with.  The purpose of `drop_first` is to avoid the [dummy trap](http://facweb.cs.depaul.edu/sjost/csc423/documents/dummy-variable-trap.htm):

```
>>> y = data['cash_flow']
>>> x = data.drop(['cash_flow', 'industry'], axis=1)
>>> sm.OLS(y, x).fit()
<statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResultsWrapper object at 0x115b87cf8>
```

Lastly,  just a small pointer: it helps to try to avoid naming references with names that shadow built-in object types, such as `dict`.

Comment: As alternative to using pandas for creating the dummy variables, the formula interface automatically converts string categorical through patsy.

Comment: @Josef Can you elaborate on how to (cleanly) do that? As Pandas is converting any string to np.object. And I get `ValueError: Pandas data cast to numpy dtype of object. Check input data with np.asarray(data).` when I tried to use a DataFrame with some columns being strings.

Answer (score 20):

I also had this problem as well and have lots of columns needed to be treated as categorical, and this makes it quite annoying to deal with `dummify`. And converting to `string` doesn't work for me.

For anyone looking for a solution without onehot-encoding the data,
The R interface provides a nice way of doing this:

```py
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dict = {'industry': ['mining', 'transportation', 'hospitality', 'finance', 'entertainment'],
  'debt_ratio':np.random.randn(5), 'cash_flow':np.random.randn(5) + 90} 

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict)

x = df[['debt_ratio', 'industry']]
y = df['cash_flow']

# NB. unlike sm.OLS, there is "intercept" term is included here
smf.ols(formula="cash_flow ~ debt_ratio + C(industry)", data=df).fit()
```

Reference:
https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/example_formulas.html#categorical-variables

Comment: How to predict with cat features in this case?

Comment: It should be similar to what has been discussed here.
https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/examples/notebooks/generated/predict.html

Comment: Personally, I would have accepted this answer, it is much cleaner (and I don't know R)!

Comment: the function `.get_prediction()` doesnt seem to work on this method. I need to get the confidence/prediction intervals out. Is there a way to do this with the smf r syntax?

Comment: @OceanScientist In the latest version of statsmodels (v0.12.2), `.get_prediction()` method works.

Comment: Otherwise model.predict(dataframe) works.

Answer (score 0):

Just another example from a similar case for categorical variables, which gives correct result compared to a statistics course given in R (Hanken, Finland).

```
import wooldridge as woo
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import numpy as np

df = woo.dataWoo('beauty')
print(df.describe)

df['abvavg'] = (df['looks']>=4).astype(int) # good looking
df['belavg'] = (df['looks']<=2).astype(int) # bad looking

df_female = df[df['female']==1]
df_male = df[df['female']==0]

results_female = smf.ols(formula = 'np.log(wage) ~ belavg + abvavg',data=df_female).fit()
print(f"FEMALE results, summary \n {results_female.summary()}")

results_male = smf.ols(formula = 'np.log(wage) ~ belavg + abvavg',data=df_male).fit()
print(f"MALE results, summary \n {results_male.summary()}")
```

Terveisin, Markus