# how to specify a variable to be categorical variable in regression using "statsmodels"

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

I was trying to fit a model using "statsmodels", the codes and results are here:

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm

data = {'y':[3895,3798,5899,3748,5719,7140,5397,4697,6850,11995],
        'x1':[26,35,18,31,18,23,41,25,25,17],
        'x2':[3,5,5,5,5,4,5,4,4,5],
        'x3':[3,2.5,2.5,3,2,2.5,3,3,2,2.5]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
x = df[['x1','x2','x3']]
y = df[['y']]

x = sm.add_constant(x) # add intercept to the model
model = sm.OLS(y, x).fit()
results = model.summary()
print(results)
```

[image]

These results are alright, but I was wondering how could I specify "x2" as a categorical variable in the model. Thanks.

Comment: Does [this question in OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55738056/using-categorical-variables-in-statsmodels-ols-class) answers to yours? Use the `.get_dummies()` method from pandas as described in the other question.

Comment: Have you tried anything, done any research? Also, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.